# Creating Appointment using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have 3 tables in a mysql database

An appointment table:

```
CREATE TABLE `create_appointment` (
      `aid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `aTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
      `aDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `did` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

A doctor table :

```
  CREATE TABLE `doctor` (
      `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `speciality` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

And a patient table

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

pid and did in create_appointment table are forgien keys from doctor and patient tables respectively

I want to create a form.php file where by a patient can create an appointment. And the doctor's information such as his speciality and I will also be saved since a a patient (isn't required to know a doctor's ID before reservation of appointment) . How do I go by this?

P.S Am a novice 6day old novice in php an mysql. Any help or tips will be appreciated.
 Thank you :D

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what error messsge you received or unexpected behaviour you encountered and we can help you. But do not us ask us to design sg for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user will be logged in, you should have `pid` stored in session or something, and the `did` can be determined by having a drop down of doctors or by browsing to the doctor's page and then clicking a button to make an appointment.

Other data like date and time can be done using a date picker by jQuery UI library or similar javascript library.

The `aid` is of course an auto-increment field, and the status is according to your business logic, you can start with something like "pending approval", then "approved" then "done" for example.